# Can a DynamoDB scan filter expression use an In clause with a list?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Can I pass a list to the IN clause of a scan filter expression?

I'm trying to do something like this.  It doesn't throw an error but I get no matched results.

```
ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec().withMaxResultSize(maxResults)
.withFilterExpression("#zipcode IN (:zipcode)")
.withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#zipcode", "zipcode"))
.withValueMap(new ValueMap().withList(":zipcode",Arrays.asList("12345","56789")));
```

Comment: What is the DynamoDB data type of zipcode? The IN clause can be used to check the values in SET data type (SS, NS etc) only.

Comment: It's a String.  The IN clause will match a single String. For example, .withString(":zipcode", "56789") will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the list of values to match in the FilterExpression, instead of as a list in ExpressionAttributeValues. For example:

```
ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec().withMaxResultSize(maxResults)
.withFilterExpression("#zipcode IN :z1, :z2")
.withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#zipcode", "zipcode"))
.withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":z1", "12345").withString(":z2", "56789")));
```